# How to train an L2-regularized L1 Hinge Loss SVM using vowpal wabbit?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, support-vector-machines

I'm trying to train an L2-regularized L1-hinge loss SVM using vowpal-wabbit.

I use the following commands to train and test on the `splice` dataset:

```
time vw --passes 10 -c --loss_function hinge -f model.txt -d train_vw.txt --l1 0 --l2 1
time vw -t -i model.txt -p out.txt -d test_vw.txt
perf -ACC -files test.labels out.txt -t 0.5
```

The result is an accuracy of 48%, which is terrible! On splice, other SVMs, eg liblinear, give about 84% accuracy.

If I remove the `--l2 1` bit, or reduce it to `--l2 0.001` or so, then I get ok-ish accuracy, at least 81% or so.  I'm expecting that the --l2 parameter is equivalent to the `C` parameter of other SVMs.  Am I wrong?  If so, what is the relationship between the `--l2` parameter and the standard `C` SVM parameter?

Full details of code used:

```
cat train_svmlight.txt | sed -e "s/^+1 /1 |f /" | sed -e "s/^-1 /-1 |f /" > train_vw.txt
cat test_svmlight.txt | sed -e "s/^+1 /1 |f /" | sed -e "s/^-1 /-1 |f /" > test_vw.txt
time vw --passes 10 -c --loss_function hinge -f model.txt -d train_vw.txt --l1 0 --l2 1
time vw -t -i model.txt -p out.txt -d test_vw.txt
cat test_vw.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sed -e 's/^-1/0/' > test.labels
perf -ACC -files test.labels out.txt -t 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe VW has a bug with loss_function=hinge. I always see that the first iteration of bfgs showing derivative = 0 issue. For sgd it didn't seem to report this anomaly but I tend not to trust it. Presumably the error is caused by the nondifferentiability of the hinge loss function (logistic and least square are both smooth).